# Is it possible to construct all the $d_i$ based only on the fact that $f(x,y,z)$ is Taylor expandable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

If we have a function of three variables $x,y,$ and $z$ in the following form

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{e^{[x+y+z]}}{d_1d_2}+\frac{e^{[x-y-z]}}{d_2d_3}+\frac{e^{[-x-y+z]}}{d_3d_1}$$

where $d_1$, $d_2$, and $d_3$ are linear combinations of $x$, $y$, and $z$, is it possible to construct all the $d_i$ based only on the fact that $f(x,y,z)$ is Taylor expandable?

The final solution should look like:

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{e^{[x+y+z]}}{(x+y)(y+z)}-\frac{e^{[x-y-z]}}{(x-z)(y+z)}+\frac{e^{[-x-y+z]}}{(x+y)(x-z)}$$

but I cannot see how we can find the denominators.